# Search for words in description in services(.msc)

Tags: search, services

I sometimes search for services that have been named poorly and cannot be found with, for example the first letter of the programs name.

How do I search for a specific word(s) in the description field in services.msc?

I cannot see anything in File, Action or View. Is there a 'hidden' option? There should be some way...?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 Options:

Option 1:

- Open services.msc
- Click Action > Export list and save it as text document
- Now you can use search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) in notepad to  find what you need.

Option 2:

You could use something like [Hilitext](http://www.fanix.com/hilitext.html) to search for text anywhere on your screen.